# Cython malloc struct to python

Tags: python, malloc, cython

How can I go about converting this line into python from cython. I want to try to avoid using any cython if possible.

```
cdef qnode *q = <qnode *> malloc((4 * height * width + 1) * sizeof(qnode))
```

Here are the struct details and I am getting  a subscriptable error. The top is the original cython and the bottom is my new class.

```
#ctypedef struct qnode:
#    int row
#    int col
#    int layer
#    int orig_row
#    int orig_col

class qnode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 0
        self.col = 0
        self.layer = 0
        self.orig_row = 0
        self.orig_col = 0

q = qnode()
```

This line is the main issue and I need to be able to keep this stack like operation.

```
q[-1].row = x
```

Following that how can how also go about converting the free(q) command as well.

Comment: Numpy array can be used for that but they have a significant overhead from CPython if your array is small. Python does not allow you to access pointers directly so the line does not have any strict equivalent in Python. The closest pure-Python alternative is to use buffer and packing/unpacking operation, or just class regarding your need. All of that is slow.

Comment: To me this looks like they just want to create a Python list of `qnode`